# Cache synchronized between cores

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency, synchronization, processor

Each processor core can have its own cache. Cache is write through and read through. If two threads are running on different cores and are synchronized by semaphores can it happen that on read of memory location caches have different version of this location or are they somehow transparently synchronized by processor? I am interested in x86 and RISC.

Comment: semaphores are not a hardware feature and are implemented differently in different languages. What language and library do you mean?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I told about semaphores only to indicate that *time of execution* of code lines is synchronized correctly. What I am really interested in is whether cache is synchronized transparently for programmer. If not whether there are some assembly commands to synchronize it and if typical language say C++ and threading library (windows or linux) use those command to synchronize e.g. when calling semaphore functions.

Answer (score 0):

Every SMP machine you are likely to use has cache coherency implemented in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

According to Linux documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt):
for while the caches are expected to be coherent, there's no guarantee that that coherency
will be ordered.  This means that whilst changes made on one CPU will
eventually become visible on all CPUs, there's no guarantee that they will
become apparent in the same order on those other CPUs.